# I can't mark two answers correct, so how should I curate this nugget of knowledge?

Tags: discussion, support

I have collated both answers into a new answer, but don't want to give myself the points or kudos for getting a correct answer when I'm just clarifying two answers?

Hope this makes sense: see here:

[Can I stop Visual Studio spawning a web browser when I start debugging?](https://superuser.com/questions/357736/can-i-stop-visual-studio-spawning-a-web-browser-when-i-start-debugging/378740#378740)

Thanks!

Comment: Get all your friends to sign up and upvote both the answers ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Accept the answer you like better. Comment on it with clarification, or suggest an edit that doesn't change the answer too much, but maybe improves the explanation. Upvote all answers you like or that helped you.